# CSS3 arc div or draw an arc

Tags: css

With css3 is it possible arc a div or draw and arc like the image below... I've seen a few examples for circles but not an arc.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it with `border-radius`.

See an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jQ5gu/

Comment: is there a method to make the corners stay round when the height is 42px?